# Eclipse - "Java was started but returned exit code=1"

Tags: java, eclipse, startup

When I run eclipse I get the error in the title. Here is a picture of this error:

[image]

After searching around for what to do, I found two options. The first was to add the following lines to the ini file:

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe

My ini file looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

So I added the vm command above the vmargs command but to no avail.

Next I tried adding in the line:

> -XX:-UseCompressedOops

Which seemed to work for a lot of people. I tried adding this line at the end of my ini file, in place of the "XX:MaxPermSizeSize=384m" line, and with and without the vm command. Nothing seems to work. Whenever I used the "-XX:-UseCompressedOops" line, it gave me the error:

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

**EDIT:**

Fixed the problem by realizing I was trying use a 32 bit version of java instead of a 64 bit version.

Comment: What Java Version do you use? x64?

Comment: Are you able to run JRE without problems? Did you try running a java program without using eclipse?

Comment: dumb question but did you already try to run it in Administrator mode? if so try the vm fix with java instead of javaw

Comment: @Codebender Yeah I seem to be able to run other java programs, like jar files and such.

Comment: @12dollar Yes I tried running in Administrator mode, I tried the vm fix with java and it still doesn't work. :(